# How to loop through pandas data frame and rename all of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that has several columns that I would like to rename.

```
+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| FIPS | ('Active', '03/22/2020') | ('Active', '03/23/2020') | ('Active', '03/25/2020') |
+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 1001 |                        1 |                        4 |                        8 |
| 1003 |                        4 |                        6 |                        9 |
| 1005 |                        6 |                        8 |                        9 |
+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I want to rename all the columns after the first column. Changing ('Active', '03/22/2020') to Active_20200322 and so on. This is what I want my final output to be:

```
+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| FIPS | Active_20200322          | Active_20200323          |  Active_20200325
+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 1001 |                        1 |                        4 |                        8 |
| 1003 |                        4 |                        6 |                        9 |
| 1005 |                        6 |                        8 |                        9 |
+------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Is there a way I can do this using a loop?

Comment: look into `pandas.DataFrame.columns`. it's a list of column names, and you can change them there... also `pandas.DataFrame.rename` can be used to rename columns.

Comment: The part I'm struggling with is pulling the two information I need from the current column name to create the new column name.

Comment: @ManroopSingh Are column names tuples? or are they just simple strings enclosed in `()`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma They are just strings enclosed in ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with a custom `mapper` function which takes the input arg as column name and map this name according to specified requirements:

```
import re 

def mapper(c):
    m = re.search(r"\('([^']+).*?'([^']+)'\)", c)
    return "{0}_{3}{1}{2}".format(m.group(1), *m.group(2).split('/')) if m else c

df.columns = df.columns.map(mapper)
```

Result:

```
   FIPS  Active_20200322  Active_20200323  Active_20200325
0  1001                1                4                8
1  1003                4                6                9
2  1005                6                8                9
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to write a function to fix the column names. You can then create a dict comprehension and pass this to `DataFrame.rename` to fix them. For example, something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime

def fix_column_name(val):
    if 'Active' in val:
        val = re.sub(r'[\(\)\']', '', val)
        s1, s2 = re.split(',\s*', val)
        s2 = datetime.strptime(s2, '%m/%d/%Y')
        return f'{s1}_{s2.strftime("%Y%m%d")}'
    return val

# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'FIPS': [1001, 1003, 1005],
 "('Active', '03/22/2020')": [1, 4, 6],
 "('Active', '03/23/2020')": [4, 6, 8],
 "('Active', '03/25/2020')": [8, 9, 9]})

print(df)
```

[out]

```
   FIPS  ('Active', '03/22/2020')  ('Active', '03/23/2020')  ('Active', '03/25/2020')
0  1001                         1                         4                         8
1  1003                         4                         6                         9
2  1005                         6                         8                         9
```

---

```
d = {c:fix_column_name(c) for c in df.columns}

df = df.rename(d, axis=1)

print(df)
```

[out]

```
   FIPS  Active_20200322  Active_20200323  Active_20200325
0  1001                1                4                8
1  1003                4                6                9
2  1005                6                8                9
```